# How Retrofit library working faster than default AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, retrofit, retrofit2

Today i used `retrofit` library in my project instead of `AsyncTask` because it is faster than `HttpUrlConnection` but i am wondering how  it is faster and what mechanism they are using. I searched about that but didn't get the accurate or satisfactory answer. Please help me out to understand the concept behind it.

Comment: It's open source. Just go and read the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async task execute serially and are single threaded by default and they will wait for last call to complete before execution of next one and designed in a way so that to avoid common errors due to parallel running threads. Retrofit is not. It sends calls parallely and use ThreadPoolExecutor.

Comment: Dont forget to mark this post as answer if you understand the difference. It will also help others in future.